# Can microbursts occur at high altitudes?

Tags: weather, wind, turbulence

I was wondering whether a microburst can occur at high altitudes?

Comment: What does high altitude mean?

Answer (score 6):

Strong downbursts of air are possible at high levels also, for example in Cumulonimbus-clouds. However I wouldn't characterize them as microbursts, since the change of airflow direction is an equally dangerous and defining factor in microbursts.

[image]
<sub>(source: [weather.gov.hk](http://www.weather.gov.hk/aviat/amt_e/cause/microburst_e.gif))</sub>

The head/tailwind parts don't exist at higher altitudes and you would experience the downdraft merely as turbulence.